# changing the cell base on another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, data-manipulation

I want to create a new column with the value of another dataframe in this case if cell in df1==1 new value is the current df2 cell

```
df1 <- c("1","2","3","4","5")
df2 <- c("a","b","c","d","e")

df <- cbind(df1,df2)
df
     df1 df2
[1,] "1" "a"
[2,] "2" "b"
[3,] "3" "c"
[4,] "4" "d"
[5,] "5" "e"
```

Expected answer would be;

```
     df1 df2  my.column
[1,] "1" "a"     "a"
[2,] "2" "b"     "2"
[3,] "3" "c"     "3"
[4,] "4" "d"     "4"
[5,] "5" "e"     "5"
```

many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ifelse` :

```
transform(df, my_col = ifelse(df1 == 1, df2, df1))

#  df1 df2 my_col
#1   1   a      a
#2   2   b      2
#3   3   c      3
#4   4   d      4
#5   5   e      5
```

Equivalent in `dplyr` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%mutate(my_col = ifelse(df1 == 1, df2, df1))
```

---

Or copy `df1` values first and then replace.

```
df$my_col <- df$df1
df$my_col[df$df1 == 1] <- df$df2[df$df1 == 1]
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(df1,df2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` will do the assign in place

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, my_col := df1][df1 == 1, my_col := df2]
df
#   df1 df2 my_col
#1:   1   a      a
#2:   2   b      2
#3:   3   c      3
#4:   4   d      4
#5:   5   e      5
```

---

Or with `fifelse`

```
setDT(df)[, my_col := fifelse(df1 == 1, df2, df1)]
```

Or using `fcase`

```
setDT(df)[, my_col := fcase(df1 == 1, df2, default = df1)]
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(df1,df2, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```